# Depression and happiness

Tags: meaning, antonyms, semantics

- Are "depression" and "happiness" antonyms?
- Are they mutually exclusive?
- Does the absence of one imply the presence of the other?

(I am trying to ascertain the semantic validity of using depression-metrics as a gauge of happiness)

Comment: You could fill a book trying to define *happiness*, and another one for *depression*. In fact, there are already zillions, and mostly they don't agree with each other. Voting to close.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i.e. "Too hard, I won't bother trying."

Comment: not *too hard*, no. It's just that EL&U is really after questions that can be answered precisely. Ideally with a yes/no or similar. This question could go on and on. It's really just an invitation to have a philosophical debate, which probably isn't what most people here want.

Comment: you might wish to consider that although the odd person suggests it now and again, there is no **philosophy.se**, because people who understand how stackexchange works will realise that particular one wouldn't (work).

Comment: @Fumble: there is one now: philosophy.stackexchange.com. But by your same argument, the OPs question wouldn't be a good fit there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Depression* is an ambiguous term that can refer to a [mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depression_%28mood%29) or [mental disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_depressive_disorder). *Happiness* can also be seen as a mood but is more commonly considered a [state of mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happiness).

One could plausibly make the argument that both *depression* and *happiness* are emotions or moods or states of mind. For them to serve as antonyms they would need to operate on the same domain. Unfortunately, they are both nearly impossible to define without using other emotions, moods, states of mind as comparators. The idea of defining them as antonyms, for example, would be more useful when determining whether someone *was* depressed or happy. But a more typical antonym for *happiness* is *sadness* and the antonym for *depression* is *elation*.

As for the terms being mutually exclusive, they *can* be if (a) working within the same domain and (b) are being defined that way for the purpose of determining which one someone is. But they aren't necessarily so. Someone who is clinically depressed could feel a moment of happiness or vice versa.

But in no domain, shared or otherwise, would the absence of one imply the presence of the other. Someone who is entirely apathetic wouldn't feel either.

The summary:

- You can use "depression" and "happiness" as antonyms if you want but not everyone will agree with you
- You can define them as mutually exclusive but not everyone will agree with you
- The absence of one does not imply the presence of the other

> (I am trying to ascertain the semantic validity of using depression-metrics as a gauge of happiness)

As for this goal, I recommend asking people in the fields of psychiatry and psychology instead of linguistics. We can tell you how people use the words; they can tell you about the actual moods and states of minds themselves. The odds are pretty good someone has an excellent answer to this intent but you aren't likely to find them here.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if depression is the norm and happiness a mental disorder /Marvin

Answer (score 1):

Not antonyms, no. For sure, a depressed person is unlikely to be happy, but one can be unhappy without being depressed.

Comment: depressed > content > happy - Trying, "to ascertain the semantic validity of using depression-metrics as a gauge of happiness," is the wrong route; each of those words need their own "gauge".

Answer (score -2):

This article from [wikipedia might help you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion)

[And this image of basic emotions.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Emotions.gif)

Comment: This is a very weak answer, in fact it's not even an answer. There are two links, the second is broken, so readers are left with a link to Wikipedia's page about "emotion"